# PHP if nothing displays in if statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

Here is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
        )
```

here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
foreach($results as $row) {
    if($row['id'] > 10) {
        echo $row['id'];
    }
}
?>
```

since there is no id that is greater than 10, i want it to:

```
echo 'Nothing found';
```

how can i do that? thanks.

Comment: `else { echo 'Nothing found'; }` - *Simple enough*.

Comment: ...seems like a *trick* question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `else` to the if statment would be anything that is less than 10. i want it to show "nothing found" if there is nothing in the if statement that is greater than 10.

Comment: Your `if($row['id'] > 10)` and your *"since there is no id that is greater than 10, i want it to"* - my `else` should be doing the job here; I knew this was a trick question.

Comment: this is db-related; you can do this in your query instead, it'd even be faster.

Comment: What about using array_filter , I have tried one on my answer

Comment: Given some of the answers below, I have to say that those basically do what I suggested. `if(!$foundone)` is the same as `else`. And the ternary method `echo ($output == '') ? 'Nothing found' : $output;` same thing. Again; I'd of done it in the query instead, it would have been a lot faster. But hey, if you're happy with that, stick with those.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Only difference is, that an `else` would have printed 3 times "nothing found". But I agree, that if it's db related, a solution with a filter there would be better.

Comment: @Jeff Yeah, come to think of it and you making me "think outside the box"... would have failed on my part. Yet, in the query as I thought afterwards would have worked wonders. I'd of popped in an answer but they probably would have asked me how it worked; I think I was wise not to ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set a boolean flag:

```
$foundone=false;

foreach($results as $row) {
   if($row['id'] > 10) { 
       $foundone = true;
       echo $row['id'];
   }
}

if(!$foundone) {
  echo "Nothing found";
}
```

Alternative: sort the array (via usort f.e.) and check for the highest value:

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) { return $a['id']>$b['id']; });
if ($array[count($array)-1]['id'])>10) {
   echo "found an id higher than 10!";
} else {
   echo "nothing found";
}
```

But I doubt this would be faster and/or easier to read and maintain.

Comment: i would also suggest adding a `break` after `$foundone = true;` to stop processing, unless it's required to process all of em. and obviously, move the `echo` outside the `if`statement

Comment: well, he might want to print all of the matches, that are greater 10. At least that's how I understood the request.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to says that nothing was found only once, you could do:

```
$output = '';
foreach($results as $row) {
    if($row['id'] > 10) $output .= $row['id'];
}
echo ($output == '') ? 'Nothing found' : $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using array_filter.  Sorry for late response

```
$arr=array
(
     array
        (
            'id' => 5
        ),

     array
        (
            'id' => 9
        ),

    array
        (
            'id' => 2
        )
    );


$new_arr = array_filter($arr, function ($elem) {
                  return $elem['id'] > 10
           });
if(count($new_arr)==0){
     echo 'Nothing found';
}
```

Comment: `if ($elem['id'] > 10 { return true; }` => `return $elem['id'] > 10;`

Comment: For those who do not know, `array_filter()` is still a looper / iterator.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest keeping track of the maximum ID.

```
$maxId = 0;
foreach($results as $row){
    // safely store the id
    $id = isset($row['id']) && is_numeric($row['id']) ? $row['id'] : 0;
    // check if $id is bigger than $maxId and set
    $maxId = $id > $maxId ? $id : $maxId;
    // print the id
    echo $id;
}

if($maxId > 10){
    ...
}
```